# Codeigniter prev_link and next_link link not rendered correct

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pagination

In config array I use this part of code:

```
        $config['prev_link'] = '<a class="round-icon" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Previous Page"><i class="iconfont-angle-left"></i></a>';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $config['next_link'] = '<a class="round-icon" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Next Page"><i class="iconfont-angle-right"></i></a>';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

for the next and previous button. And what it generate :

```
<li>
    <a href="...../categories/index/18"></a>
    <a class="round-icon" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Next Page" data-original-title="">
        <i class="iconfont-angle-right"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

so you can see that `<a href="...../categories/index/18"></a>` is not wrapping everything. Why is it not happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put all your wrappers on the `next_tag_open` and `next_tag_close` only the text you want to appear on the link, that is what you will put on the `next_link` config.

```
$config['next_link'] = '<i class="iconfont-angle-right"></i>';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li><a class="round-icon" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Next Page">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
```

`next_tag_open . next_link . next_tag_close`

Comment: If it is that logic you posted `next_tag_open . next_link . next_tag_close` shouldn't mine work also? I need .round-icon wrapped too in <a>. Anyway here is what I get using your code:
`<li>
    <a class="round-icon" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Previous Page" data-original-title="" title=""></a>
    <a href="...../index.php/categories/index/">
        <i class="iconfont-angle-left"></i>
    </a>

</li>`

Comment: @DusanMalic Codeigniter adds a `href` value automatically, which is the numbers. if you add another `href` you are trying to wrap an `href` within another `href` and that is a bad design, why not wrap the tooltip with a span. or are you using `ajax`? which is why you are doing what you are currently doing.

Comment: I used some html template for that. Wrapping it as span done job. Thanks